# Mobile Responsive design

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

The idea would be to center the two elements, 
despite working perfectly on the desktop they get misaligned on mobile.

(in some the bottom element is partially hidden on the left)
as you can see here: http://i61.tinypic.com/x23xh3.png

have any idea?
this is the url:
http://ikariampt.com/resolute/

I don't have a smartphone 
any suggestion where I could debug it?
Firefox and Chrome tools/mobile profiles seems to have no effect but on the screen (thus working well)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They appear centered on my end in Safari 7.0. If you're on mac you can use Xcode and the iOS simulator to debug.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Josh, but I wish I had it!

I run it through CSS validator and there was a bracket missing, it's fixed now.